# Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component [react-native-webview]

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

My webview is returning error

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

My project is a clean project and only have webview installed and my code is very simple in the return.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }} />;
</View>
```

**Dependencies:** 
react-native-webview = ^10.9.0 
react-native = 0.61.5

Comment: It's because you have `;` in the end. It's considered as text string

Comment: Oh my bad. Thank you